# printf modifying a string

Tags: c, printf

Using `printf` to print `"\4unix\5lancs\2ac\2uk\0"` I find, instead of a print in the form of `♦unix♣lancs☻ac☻uk`, I get garbage (`♫ ,►E¦§Qh ↕`).

I cannot find an explanation for this; I use the following method to tokenise a string:

```
/**
 * Encode the passed string into a string as defined in the RFC.
 */
char * encodeString(char *string) {
    char stringCopy[128];
    char encodedString[128] = "";
    char *token;

    /* We copy the passed string as strtok mutates its argument. */
    strcpy(stringCopy, string);

    /* We tokenise the string on periods. */
    token = strtok(stringCopy, ".");

    while (token != NULL) {
        char encodedToken[128] = "";

        /* Encode the token. */
        encodedToken[0] = (char) strlen(token);
        strcat(encodedToken, token);

        /* Add the encodedString token to the encodedString string. */
        strcat(encodedString, encodedToken);

        /* Prepare for the next iteration. */
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }

    /* A null character is appended already to the encoded string. */

    return encodedString;
}
```

And the following code in my driver to print the result when tokenising `"unix.lancs.ac.uk"`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *foo = "unix.lancs.ac.uk";
    char *bar = encodeString(foo);

    printf("%s\n", bar);

    return 0;
}
```

If I add a `printf` to print `encodedString` at the end of the `encodeString` method, I don't get garbage printed out (rather, `♦unix♣lancs☻ac☻uk` twice).

(Upon debugging I notice the actual memory contents is changed.)

Can anyone explain this phenomenon to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to the array `encodedString`, which is local to the `encodeString()` function and has automatic storage duration.

This memory is no longer valid after that function exits, which is what is causing your problem.

You can fix it by giving `encodedString` static storage duration:

```
static char encodedString[128];

encodedString[0] = '\0';
```

(You can no longer use the initialiser to empty the array, because arrays with static storage duration maintain their values from one invocation of the function to the next.)

Comment: Cheers! But that doesn't explain why if I call printf within the encodeString method the memory doesn't then get freed by the time I call the printf in main, do you know why that happens?

Comment: That's just one of the many weird manifestations you can get when you break the rules in C.  The difference is because the extra call to `printf()` inside the function alters what's on the stack - and its this left-over stuff on the stack that the erroneuous `printf`  call in the main function runs into.

Answer (score 4):

When you say:

```
 return encodedString;
```

you are returning a local variable, which will have ceased to exist by the time you come to use it. A quick hack would be to make encodedString static.

Answer (score 3):

**DO NOT** use functions that return strings.

Send the string address as paremeter and change it in the function.

The compiler should display a warning. **Don't ignore compiler warnings especially in C.**

Your function should be like this:

```
void encodeString(char *string, char *encodedString)
{
.
.
.
}
```

See [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1471051&page=4)

Comment: Cheers for the advice! I see that's how a lot of the standard methods work anyway.

Comment: First sentence is little bit strict, second however VERY TRUE. Try this: char* encodeString(const char *string, char *encodedString);  where return value is encodedString (and you can still use it in expressions, etc)